# Фильтр по подстроке Excel

Tags: excel

Есть таблица с поставщиками. В колонке D через запятую перечисляются номера заявлений. Необходима фильтрация поставщиков по номерам заявлений, как обычная фильтрация колонки; из-за большого количества номеров в одной ячейке выполнить ее в нужном виде невозможно.

Вопрос: каким образом можно оставить тех поставщиков, у которых, например, будет присутствовать номер заявления 8037531247?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: *В колонке D через запятую перечисляются номера заявлений.* И кто ж это безобразие придумал-то? трудно было три строки сделать, по одному заявлению на строку?

Comment: *каким образом можно оставить тех поставщиков, у которых, например, будет присутствовать номер заявления 8037531247?* Фильтр - Текстовые фильтры - Содержит - "8037531247"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Указать в какой-нибудь ячейке, какой номер заявления хочется найти, например в E2.

Затем, в ближайшем свободном столбце вставить дополнительную формулу, например в E3:

```
=ЕСЛИ(ЕОШ(НАЙТИ($E$2;D3;1));"нет";"есть")
```

И скопировать/протянуть эту формулу по всем поставщикам.
Результатом работы формулы станет текст `нет` или `есть`.
Как вариант, можно сделать автофильтр по значениям этого столбца, где при выборе `есть` отфильтруются нужные поставщики.